# Android: animate the alpha of single Path on a canvas

Tags: android, animation, canvas, path

I would like to animate a single Path on the android canvas.

```
public class MyView extends View {
    private Path paths[];
    protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas ) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth( 8 );
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(75, 11);
        path.quadTo(62, 87, 10, 144);
        canvas.drawPath( path, paint );
        paths[0] = path;

        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(50, 100);
        path.lineTo(150, 200);
        canvas.drawPath( path, paint );
        paths[1] = path;
    }
}
```

Now I have paths[], I would like to animate each one separately.  I would like it to change alpha like it was growing. At first there is just a little dot, then it grows into a line, repeat.

Can it be done?

How?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new float ranging from 0 to 1 that keeps the current animation percentage and use it to set the current alpha

```
public class MyView extends View {
     private Path paths[];
     private float mAnimPercentage = 0.0f;

    private static final int clip(int value){  //forces the value to be between 0 and 255
        return Math.max(0, Math.min(255, value));
    }
    protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas ) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth( 8 );
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(75, 11);
        path.quadTo(62, 87, 10, 144);
        //edited here
        paint.setAlpha(clip(mAnimPercentage*255*2));
        canvas.drawPath( path, paint );
        paths[0] = path;

        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(50, 100);
        path.lineTo(150, 200);
        //edited here
        paint.setAlpha(clip(-127 + mAnimPercentage*255*2));   //the biggest is the negative value, the latter this path will show, the biggest is the number multiplied by mAnimPercentage, the fastest this path will get completely opaque
        canvas.drawPath( path, paint );
        paths[1] = path;
        mAnimPercentage+= 0.01; //FIXME this is for TEST only, you should update it with an animator
        postInvalidate();
    }
}
```